# initContainer does not start when passing an env and there are no logs

Tags: docker, kubernetes, environment-variables

I am using a single Docker image, which contains a `.war` and a `.jar` to execute as both an `initContainer` and a `container`.

If the environment variable `DATA_MIGRATION` with value `true` is present, then the script `CMD /myuser/entry-point.sh` contains logic to run the `.jar`.

If `DATA_MIGRATION` is not set as an environment variable, `entry-point.sh` will execute the `.war` file instead.

The problem is that when I include the `DATA_MIGRATION` env on the `initContainer`, the container never starts and there are no logs. When I remove the env declaration, the `initContainer` will start but it runs the `.war` which is not desired.

How can I properly pass the env to control the behaviour of the shell script inside the Docker containers?

Kubernetes deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: ref-app
  name: ref-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ref-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ref-app
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: ref-app-database-migration
          image: artifactory.com/ref-docker-local/dev/ref-proj:dev-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-851e2d5
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9080
          env:
            - name: DATABASE_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-secret
                  key: username
            - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-secret
                  key: password
            - name: DATA_MIGRATION
              value: "true"
      containers:
        - name: ref-app
          image: artifactory.com/ref-docker-local/dev/ref-proj:dev-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-851e2d5
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9080
          env:
            - name: DATABASE_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-secret
                  key: username
            - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-secret
                  key: password
```

Snippet of `describe pod`:

```
Init Containers:
  ref-app-database-migration:
    Container ID:   docker://b1ada5e7b8b96c2dca49bca5913d03f313c546f92c112f3910aa1bfc068af9a1
    Image:          artifactory.com/ref-docker-local/dev/ref-proj:dev-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-851e2d5
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:2366a284564c16e031de5df5fb7c8e78e289f50fe9e2488f654344a5b1cb858a
    Port:           9080/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Mon, 22 May 2023 15:16:16 +0100
      Finished:     Mon, 22 May 2023 15:16:16 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  1
    Environment:
      DATABASE_USERNAME:       <set to the key 'username' in secret 'db-secret'>  Optional: false
      DATABASE_PASSWORD:       <set to the key 'password' in secret 'db-secret'>  Optional: false
      DATA_MIGRATION:  true
..
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  13s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/ref-app-985fd75cd-bz8w6 to docker-desktop
  Normal   Pulled     11s (x2 over 12s)  kubelet            Container image "artifactory.com/ref-docker-local/dev/ref-proj:dev-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-851e2d5" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    11s (x2 over 12s)  kubelet            Created container ref-app-database-migration
  Normal   Started    11s (x2 over 12s)  kubelet            Started container ref-app-database-migration
  Warning  BackOff    9s (x2 over 10s)   kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

`kubectl logs deployment/ref-app` output:

```
Defaulted container "ref-app" out of: ref-app, ref-app-database-migration (init)
Error from server (BadRequest): container "ref-app" in pod "ref-app-985fd75cd-mn7f2" is waiting to start: PodInitializing
```

Comment: It looks like your `entry-point.sh` exited with status 1.  What is in that script?  Does `kubectl logs deployment/ref-app` give you any useful information?

Comment: (Looking at your edit, you may need a `kubectl logs -c ref-app-database-migration` option to display the logs from the init container rather than the main container.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I get `POD or TYPE/NAME is a required argument for the logs command` when trying `kubectl logs -c ref-app-database-migration`

Comment: I needed `kubectl logs -c ref-app-database-migration ref-app-985fd75cd-mn7f2`